# 列名が無い、同じ構造のDataFrameの値を足し算したい

Tags: python, pandas

列名が無い、同じ構造のデータフレームの足し算を以下のように書きましたが、エラーメッセージが出ました。
どのように修正したらよいでしょうか？
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

現状のコード:

```
names=['time','交通量']
df1= pd.read_csv(r'file1.csv', index_col= 0 ,names=cols_name)
df2= pd.read_csv(r'file2.csv', index_col= 0 ,names=cols_name)
df_sum = (df1.set_index('time') + df2.set_index('time')).reset_index()
print(df_sum)
```

エラーメッセージ:

```
None of ['time'] are in the columns
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_csv()` で `index_col= 0` つまり日時項目がインデックスに指定されてるので,

- 再度 `set_index()` する必要はないはず
- すでにインデックスに指定されてるので, `df['time']` の項目は存在しない

```py
df1.columns   # カラムは 1つ
# Index(['交通量'], dtype='object')

df1.reset_index().columns   # reset_index() すれば time 項目が現れる
# Index(['time', '交通量'], dtype='object')
```

以上のことからこのように

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
csv1 = io.StringIO('''
2023/1/1,11
2023/1/2,12
2023/1/3,13
2023/1/4,14
2023/1/5,15
''')
csv2 = io.StringIO('''
2023/1/1,21
2023/1/2,22
2023/1/3,23
2023/1/4,24
2023/1/5,25
''')

cols_name=['time','交通量']
df1= pd.read_csv(csv1, index_col= 0 ,names=cols_name)
df2= pd.read_csv(csv2, index_col= 0 ,names=cols_name)
df_sum = df1 + df2
display(df_sum)
```

---

(**update**)

#### 日付が一致していない場合について

コメントの「もし日付は前1日にしたら」の意味がよく読み取れないけれど, その後の詳細も記されないので, (とりあえず)日付が一致していない場合を示します

- 単に日付をずらすだけなら CSVを書き換えるだけの話
- 2つの DataFrameが同様にずれるなら, 結果に意味はない

まず `time`カラムがインデックス扱いだとその後が面倒なことと, また文字列扱いなので, 以下のようにインデックス無しで, 日付を解釈 (`parse_dates=` 指定)
その後 2つの DataFrameを合わせ, 合計を算出
... の手順で行っています

```py
>>> df1 = pd.read_csv(csv1, names=cols_name, parse_dates=[0])
>>> df1.dtypes
time    datetime64[ns]
交通量           int64
dtype: object
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv(csv2, names=cols_name, parse_dates=[0])
>>> df2['time'] = df2['time'] -pd.offsets.Day(1)
>>> df2
        time  交通量
0 2022-12-31   21
1 2023-01-01   22
2 2023-01-02   23
3 2023-01-03   24
4 2023-01-04   25
>>> df = df1.merge(df2, on='time', how='outer').fillna(0)
>>> df
        time  交通量_x  交通量_y
0 2022-12-31    0.0   21.0
1 2023-01-01   11.0   22.0
2 2023-01-02   12.0   23.0
3 2023-01-03   13.0   24.0
4 2023-01-04   14.0   25.0
5 2023-01-05   15.0    0.0
>>> df['交通量合計'] = df['交通量_x'] +df['交通量_y']
>>> df
        time  交通量_x  交通量_y  交通量合計
0 2022-12-31    0.0   21.0   21.0
1 2023-01-01   11.0   22.0   33.0
2 2023-01-02   12.0   23.0   35.0
3 2023-01-03   13.0   24.0   37.0
4 2023-01-04   14.0   25.0   39.0
5 2023-01-05   15.0    0.0   15.0
>>>
```

Comment: 追加質問ですが、もし日付は前1日にしたら（2023/1/1→2022/12/31、2023/1/2→2023/1/1）、何を書き換えたらいいですか？ありがとうございます。

Comment: カラム Aの日付が合ったものどうしを加算する。
そのために日付をずらしてみる。
という意味なら, この質問の範囲内と言えるので回答を追記することは可能です。
でも別の意味の質問なら(コメントの「日付は前1日に」の意味が読み取れないけど), 元の質問と違った方向のものなら別質問(新たに)用意したほうがよいです